positioning background depending on size of element and viewport
The fixed background on the page I want to make has an area at the top that I would consider 'optional'.
When the elements on the body occupy the entire screen (or more), I want this optional area to shrink accordingly.
The element with the background is the body which grows outside the html element which overflows.
The body's min-height is 100vh.
The background has these properties: center fixed no-repeat.
I thought it would be easy: background-position-y: clamp(-12vh, calc(100% - 100vh), 0px)
But that doesn't work.
It appears that the percentage is the culprit because, with calc(1% - 1000%), the background offset is still 0.
I've figured out already that the percentage doesn't signify the size of the container but aligns an offset of the container with the corresponding offset of the background image.
Is there a way to refer to the size of the container with calc() or is there an alternative approach?
I know it could be done using Javascript, like it is done here, but preferably, I would like to avoid having to use JS.


body, div, html, p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;

  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #0ff 86%, #0f0 93%, #f00 97%) center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 200%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  /* ignore jsfiddle complaining about 'px' - it is required */
  background-position-y: clamp(-10vh, calc(100% - 100vh), 0px);
}

img {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
   height: 70vh;
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
   
   -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
   transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

img.big {
  height: 90vh;
}

.inner {
  /* it'd be nice if this worked as well */
  padding-top: clamp(-10vh, calc(100% - 100vh), 0px);
  max-width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  line-height: 11vh;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="inner">
  <p>red and this first line should gradually disappear when the monkey sticks out at the bottom (click image to toggle size)</p>
  <img id="ape" src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/08/18/813908_ape.svg" onclick="this.classList.toggle('big')">
</div>



Here's an example using jsfiddle, in case the above doesn't work:
https://jsfiddle.net/r0tLob6q/158/
Note that the red line at the top vanishes even before the monkey becomes too big.
I also want the first line of text to move away but that's a question for another day 

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Will do! Just give me a moment to throw it together.
